# React failed to compile using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React doesn't recognize Typescript syntax and a I get this error

```
    $ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts start
(node:12196) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module r
esolution of the package at C:\Users\tmerc\OneDrive\Escritorio\SoyHenry\app\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\nod
e_modules\postcss\package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.102/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\tmerc\OneDrive\Escritorio\SoyHenry\app\admin-front\pub
lic
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.

./src/components/SelectCourseAndCohort/index.tsx
SyntaxError: C:\Users\tmerc\OneDrive\Escritorio\SoyHenry\app\admin-front\src\components\SelectCourseAndCohort\index.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (12:36)

  10 | const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  11 |
> 12 | function SelectCourseAndCohort(props: PropsSelectCourseAndCohort) {
     |                                     ^
  13 |
  14 |   const { courseInfo, setCourseInfo, courses, cohorts } = props;
```

I installed the project in this computer today, in others the problem doesn't exists.
Thank u

Comment: Do you have typescript in package.json?

Comment: @RomiHalasz Yes. `"typescript": "^4.0.3",`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!
This project is a subproject, and root have node_modules too. I was having conflicts with this.
I deleted all `node_modules` in root project and all subprojects, and all `yarn.lock`. Then i did yarn and fix the problem.
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

if you use react typescript the functional component need to be like this:

```
const SelectCourseAndCohort:FC<PropsSelectCourseAndCohort> = (props) =>{
//
}
```

it's due to React in TypeScript that you need to import FC or FunctionalComponent to access those stuff unlike react in JavaScript.

and another question why you use react-script start
and not just npm start this due the same

Comment: Doesn't work. Now says that expected '(', like if not recognize that I'm using TS.
I use 'yarn start' and that runs react-script start

Comment: @TomásMercado can you show the code plz and package.json